# std::set has no member emplace

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, libstdc++, g++-4.7

Does g++ 4.7.2 implement `std::set::emplace`, as defined by the C++11 Standard and documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/emplace)?

I have written the following little test case:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    std::string mBar;
    bool operator<(const Foo& rhs) const
    {
        return mBar < rhs.mBar;
    }
    Foo(const std::string bar) : mBar(bar) {};
};

typedef std::set<Foo> Foos;

int main()
{
    Foos foos;
    foos.emplace(std::string("Hello"));
}
```

Under G++ 4.7.2, this fails to compile:

```
[john.dibling@somewhere hacks]$ g++ -o main.o -std=c++0x -c main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:19:10: error: ‘Foos’ has no member named ‘emplace’
```

Also fails to compile under [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/Dgteux), however it does compile under MSVC 2012 Update 1.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[It is not implemented in gcc 4.7.2.](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44436)

There is some explanation:

> Just to clarify a bit: this wasn't an *oversight*. We had the *nasty*
>   problem in the Draft C++0x Standard with std::pair, which essentially
>   made impossible adding the emplace_* members to std::map,
>   std::multimap, etc, without breaking existing user code. Thus we
>   waited on that, until things got clarified in this whole area. Now
>   it's actually possible to work on those facilities.

Your code compiles nicely with gcc 4.8.0, see [LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2ec5Ko$0).

Answer (score 5):

`emplace()` for associative containers was added in `libstdc++` for gcc 4.8.0, under gcc 4.7.2 it won't work.