# EMPLACE Issue compiling with gcc 4.7

Tags: arangodb

Hi I am trying to compile ArangoDB for ARM running DEBIAN for armhf.
2.2 didn't work, because of [this](https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/issues/972) So I tried 2.3 as suggested. The problem now is:

```
./arangod/Aql/Collections.h:87:28: error: 'class std::map<std::basic_string<char>, triagens::aql::Collection*>' has no member named 'emplace'
```

Unfortunatelly I cant install gcc 4.8 I have 4.7 for compiling aragoDB. Dows anyone know how to  go through this problem and keep going with the compile?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's simply not going to compile with gcc 4.7.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812276/stdset-has-no-member-emplace or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784771/what-to-use-in-place-of-stdmapemplace.

Comment: I can confirm that you will need gcc 4.8 or higher in order to compile. clang 3.4 is also known to compile 2.2 and devel, but I have no idea whether there is a port for your platform.

Comment: Regarding the compilation issue you mentioned in 2.2:

Comment: (note to self: should not hit return in a comment) I'll fix the compilation issue in 2.2 as well. Did not know this was a major issue. **update**: fixed in 2.2 now.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks stj! Will try to compile 2.2 again.

Comment: Has compilation been successful?

Comment: well, V8 did compile, but, then etcd failed because Go bin folder is not there. Also I can only install gccgo and I dont think it will do. I guess I will put ArangoDB in my CT project in rest for the moment

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, you will need gcc 4.8 (or higher) to compile.

The compilation issue is fixed in 2.2 and it should compile successfully now.